# ¿Como imprimir el simbolo < desde xslt?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy contruyendo un generador de clases desde base de datos SQL entre varias recomendaciones elegi  utilizar XSLT 1.0, todo me resulto bastante bien el incoveniente llego cuando deseo imprimir el simbolo < dado que lo necesito imprimir la siguiente cadena "ICollections < Entidad >". He revisado varias soluciones en la web pero sin efectividad. Utilice *.tt pero no lo elegi porque no necesita ejecutar al modificar se ejecuta. Muchas gracias de antemano por cualquier informacion.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás generando código debes tener en cuenta:

- La salida de tu xslt debe ser texto:

  Ejemplo:

  ```
  <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="no" />
  ```
- Símbolos como "<" los puedes generar apelando a sus valores numéricos y evitando que sean escapados por el parser. Por ejemplo:

  ```
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#60;</xsl:text>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT solo transforma los tags de xslt, asi que, has probado algo como:

```
ICollections < <xsl:value-of select="Entidad "/> >
```

También puedes hacer uso de las entidades predefinidas de XSLT, y usar `&#60;` para *"<"*

Puedes ver una [lista de entidades HTML](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) (esta en ingles, pero los valores es lo que importa)